# Accessing a serial port from a linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Hello Linux Kernel Driver Gurus!

I'm writing a v4l2 driver for a camera that uses a serial interface for configuration.  I'd like the driver to configure the camera, as it keeps the client code consistent across camera models.  The question is: what's the best way to access the camera's serial interface from the driver module?

From what I hear, accessing files from a kernel driver is a big no-no, but it can be done.  As such, I'm currently using the following code snippet, but it feels like a hack.

```
oldfs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

fd->f_pos=0;
fd->f_op->write(fd, data, data_len, &fd->f_pos);

set_fs(oldfs);
```

My question is really: what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume that since a serial port is involved, this must be some kind of embedded system.  After all, not many PCs even have serial ports.  I also assume that the serial port can be considered a permanent connection, at least from the user's perspective.  If that is all true, then you don't really want a TTY device.  You want to access the device as a private UART.

If you have a look at the Wolfson audio codecs (sound/soc/wm*.c) you will see an example of devices that primarily communicate over I2S but have an auxiliary I2C interface for configuration.  This is conceptually what you want, I believe.  The driver presents a unified interface to software, and issues commands to whatever hardware is appropriate.  Obviously this is much cleaner than having to expose hardware implementation details to userspace.

I couldn't find a good example of a UART driver in the kernel that works this way, but hopefully I've described what to look for.  From a practical rather than technical purity point of view, it might just be better to do file I/O from the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for this: the Wolfson Micro drivers are good examples. It's still unclear how best to use a UART (I really don't want to rewrite the UART driver!), but this is a great start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First I would advise you to find a way to do this from the userspace if possible: what you try to achieve here really is userspace code in kernel code.

But if you don't find a way to do it, this [article](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/ksys/ksys.html) shows you how to do userspace calls in kernelspace.

Since you want to access a serial port, you should have calls that tty oriented, for instance for open:

```
serial_fd = sys_open("/dev/ttyS0",  O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK))
```

Comment: I understand that this really should be in userspace, so I guess the question is: how can I have a v4l2 driver receiving ioctl's for controlling zoom that requires commands sent over a serial port?

Comment: Thanks for the great article! It explains a lot of things I didn't understand in about kernel and user spaces.